# Aurelia hello world project not working

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to the Aurelia hello world project to display in my browser. Nothing on browser at http://localhost:8080 or 9000. Its like the web server is not running. running node v8.11.0 on Win10. I've run the following from the command line:

npm i aurelia-cli -g (works fine)
au new hello-world (works fine)
cd hello-world
au run (this hangs)

I also tried:
uninstalled aurelia-cli and reinstalled
cleared the chache
deleted the hello-world dir
disabled firewall and antivirus
rebooted machine

Still having same problem, any ideas? screen dump attached.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Project structure created and configured.


Would you like to install the project dependencies?

1. Yes (Default)
   Installs all server, client and tooling dependencies needed to build the project.
2. No
   Completes the new project wizard without installing dependencies.

[Yes]>

Installing project dependencies.

 uws@9.14.0 install C:\Users\chris\hello-world\node_modules\uws
 node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0

added 2548 packages from 1909 contributors and moved 10 packages in 439.652s
Congratulations


Congratulations! Your Project "hello-world" Has Been Created!


Getting started

Now it's time for you to get started. It's easy. First, change directory into your new project's folder. You can use cd hello-world to get there. Once in your project
folder, simply run your new app with au run. Your app will run fully bundled. If you would like to have it auto-refresh whenever you make changes to your HTML, JavaScript or CSS, simply use the --watch flag
If you want to build your app for production, run au build --env prod. That's just about all there is to it. If you need help, simply run au help.


Happy Coding!

C:\Users\chris>cd hello-world

C:\Users\chris\hello-world>au run
Starting 'configureEnvironment'...
Finished 'configureEnvironment'
Starting 'runWebpack'...
(node:13760) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
Project is running at http://localhost:8080
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\chris\hello-world\dist
404s will fallback to /index.html
Finished 'runWebpack'
Hash: 3416f7890b8760877d9a
Version: webpack 4.3.0
Time: 1663ms
Built at: 2018-3-28 20:14:49
                                Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
   app.3416f7890b8760877d9a.bundle.js      3 MiB     app  [emitted]  [big]  app
vendor.3416f7890b8760877d9a.bundle.js    489 KiB  vendor  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
                           index.html  589 bytes          [emitted]
Entrypoint app [big] = app.3416f7890b8760877d9a.bundle.js
Entrypoint vendor [big] = vendor.3416f7890b8760877d9a.bundle.js
[./node_modules/aurelia-bootstrapper/dist/native-modules/aurelia-bootstrapper.js] 5.17 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-loader-webpack/dist/native-modules/aurelia-loader-webpack.js] 14.4 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-pal/dist/native-modules/aurelia-pal.js] 2.18 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-polyfills/dist/native-modules/aurelia-polyfills.js] 24.4 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry.js] 585 bytes {app} [built]
[./node_modules/aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry.js] 1.56 KiB {app} [built]
[./node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js] 175 KiB {vendor} {app} [built]
[./node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js-exposed] 65 bytes {vendor} {app} [built]
[./node_modules/process/browser.js] 5.29 KiB {vendor} {app} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {vendor} {app} [built]
[aurelia-framework] ./node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/native-modules/aurelia-framework.js 13.8 KiB {app} [built]
[aurelia-pal-browser] ./node_modules/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/native-modules/aurelia-pal-browser.js 16.9 KiB {app} [built]
[main] ./src/main.js 5.16 KiB {app} [built]
   [0] multi aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/empty-entry aurelia-webpack-plugin/runtime/pal-loader-entry aurelia-bootstrapper 52 bytes {app} [built]
   [1] multi bluebird 28 bytes {vendor} [built]
    + 262 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset      Size  Chunks  Chunk Names
    index.html  1.36 MiB       0
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.ejs] 1.03 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 527 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 519 bytes {0} [built]
```

Comment: Those messages indicate success. Also, why would you try more than one port?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with au run -watch. It doesn't work with au run.